# Dragging a tableView cell from any cell point

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my app I can move (reorder) a UITableView row without using the default edit mode to do it, I am doing this after a long-press gesture on the selected row inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, doing this, the table view enters editing mode, and then the user has to tap/hold/move on the reorder control (three paralell horizontal lines) to move the row.

I am asking if there is another way to move the row dragging it from any point of the row, not only from the reorder control? I have seen this on another app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to manually adjust the frame of `UITableViewCellReorderControl` of the `UITableViewCell`. The frame would have to be set to cell bounds.

There are many posts showing how to change the position of the reorder control. Making adjustments to them to change the control's frame should not be too complicated.

Have a look here:

[How to make reorder control of UITableViewCell in left side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141947/how-to-make-reorder-control-of-uitableviewcell-in-left-side)

[Moving reordering control to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346046/moving-reordering-control-to-left?lq=1)

[How to change Reorder Control image on ios 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910055/how-to-change-reorder-control-image-on-ios-7)

Comment: Thank you reecon, very kind of you.